# Minimum distance between two moving points on a sphere

Tags: vectors, 3d, spherical-geometry

I'm working on a vessel collision detection module for Python. With the latitude, longitude, bearing, and speed at a specific time of two vessels, how might I calculate the minimum distance between the two vessels? And the time when this would occur?

A similar question [Shortest distance between two moving points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256660/shortest-distance-between-two-moving-points) was answered in 2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

1. Consider the sphere of radius $1$ centered at $(0,0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You can always reduce to this case.
2. Write down the trajectories $\gamma_1(t)$ and $\gamma_2(t)$ as functions
   $$\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3.$$
3. If $\gamma_1(t) = \gamma_2(t)$ for some $t$, then you are done. Else find the extrema of
   $$F(t) = \|\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_2(t)\|^2,$$
   select the minima among them and then take the one with the smallest value for $F$.

Comment: To get the minimum distance, note that $F$ is the distance in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and will need conversion to a distance on the sphere.  A given distance in $\mathbb{R}^3$ maps to a unique distance on the unit sphere, though, so this isn't a problem.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Yeah, I'm implicitly using the fact that the distance relation (closer/further) is the same in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and on the sphere. Also, I take the square of the distance, which gives the correct solution and avoids differentiating square roots, simplifying things.

Comment: And if we're talking about collision detection, then the distances involved are likely to be quite small relative to the sphere, which makes this matter not be of much practical importance.